# How to show the website properly while Hosting site in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was able to publish my site successfully using the visual studio express. I was able to also add a website in the IIS manager and enabled the file browsing.

Now, every time I access the URL what I am getting is just the list of files in my published directory but I wanted to see the website I've built, meaning the login screen. How do I show my login.aspx page?

Here's my host file if this can be helpful:

**Host file**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.43.200 sample.com
```

Comment: What happens when you put in the URL for the login.aspx page?

Comment: When I type the URL manually like this: sample.com/login.aspx I receive the following error w/c I am currently searching HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Comment: Is your application pool for the directory configured for .net?

Comment: Yes. I am making progress now I'm following this post http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b07128/deploy-Asp-Net-website-on-iis-in-our-local-machine/    Though I'm having an error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error in the Config Source:
   35:             <files>
   36:                 <add value="logIn.aspx" />
   37:             </files>

Comment: Have you test it on your localhost? Is it working? What is the full error message on the server?